# Error while trying to use textarea phoenix form helpers

Tags: forms, elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to add a textarea to my form in phoenix framework.

while

```
<%= text_input f, :name, [class: "form-control", placeholder: "Votre nom *", required: ""] %>
```

works perfectly, but writing :

```
<%= textarea f, :message, [class="form-control", placeholder: "Votre message *", required: nil] %>
```

give me the error :

```
no function clause matching in Phoenix.HTML.Tag.build_attrs/3
```

here's the full code :

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Contactez-nous !</h2>
        <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <%= form_for @conn, search_path(@conn, :new), [name: :send_message], fn f -> %>
<%# <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate> %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= text_input f, :name, [class: "form-control", placeholder: "Votre nom *", required: "", 'data-validation-required-message': "Merci de bien vouloir rentrer votre nom"]  %>
                <%#<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre nom *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Merci de bien vouloir rentrer votre nom">%>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= email_input f, :email, [class: "form-control", placeholder: "Votre e-mail *", required: "", 'data-validation-required-message': "Merci de bien vouloir rentrer votre email"] %>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= telephone_input f, :phone, [class: "form-control", placeholder: "Votre téléphone *", required: "", 'data-validation-required-message': "Merci de bien vouloir rentrer votre numéro de téléphone"] %>

                <%# <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre téléphone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number."> %>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= textarea f, :message, [class="form-control", placeholder: "Votre message *", required: nil] %>
                <%#<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Votre message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez écrire un message"></textarea>%>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
              <%= submit "Search" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <%# </form> %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo after `class`:

```
<%= textarea f, :message, [class="form-control", placeholder: "Votre message *", required: nil] %>
```

should be

```
<%= textarea f, :message, [class: "form-control", placeholder: "Votre message *", required: nil] %>
```

Your code compiles fine but is equivalent to

```
<%= textarea f, :message, ["form-control", placeholder: "Votre message *", required: nil] %>
```

as the assignment operator returns the assigned value in addition to binding it to the variable which throws an error because the function expects a list of name value pairs.

Comment: Of course !! Damn this is so pathetic of me ! Thank you